# Word wrap setting in VS 2015 keeps resetting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 with update keeps resetting and I have to set it. Synchronization is turned off. Keyboard mappings to ToggleWordWrap are removed.

Any ideas why the setting is getting lost?

Comment: Where are you storing the settings?  Is it a roaming profile drive or anything of that nature?  Also, do any group policies potentially clear things such as the AppData folder? What about other configuration changes? Do those stick, or are they all getting reset?

Comment: The settings are stored where ever VS is storing the options settings. I didn't change any default behavior. Other changes are fine.

Comment: Are you using any plugins which might interfere with this setting? (VsVim, for instance) EDIT: Just in case, did you make sure there's no extra file overriding your settings?